# How to get the text value from dropped text and update the scores when the dropped text is correct answer that stores in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, drag-and-drop

i have want to develop an word quiz gaming app and i was stuck in the drag and drop method. That is drag and drop option is working fine but my confusion is how to get the text view individually from another textview for to check the correct answer from my database sqlite

I have create a database with some questions and answers i want to update the score when the dropped text is the correct answer for the question..

Please help me...

`

```
public class QuizActivity1 extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener, View.OnDragListener {
    List<Question> quesList;
    int score=0;
    int qid=1;
    Question currentQ;
    TextView textView,textView9,textView8,textView2,textView3,textView4,textView5,textView6,textView7;
    Button butNext;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DbHelper db=new DbHelper(this);
        quesList=db.getAllQuestions();
        currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
        textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textView4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        textView5=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        textView6=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        textView7=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        textView8=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        textView9=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView9);

        textView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        textView2.setOnTouchListener(this);
        textView3.setOnTouchListener(this);
        textView4.setOnTouchListener(this);

        textView5.setOnDragListener(this);
        textView6.setOnDragListener(this);
        textView7.setOnDragListener(this);
        textView8.setOnDragListener(this);



        butNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.butNext);
        setQuestionView();
        butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                //if(qid<2){
                currentQ=quesList.get(1);
                setQuestionView();
                // else{
                //Intent in = new Intent("Quiz");
               // startActivity(in);
                // Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // recreate();
               score +=4;
                textView9.setText(String.valueOf(score));
                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity1.this, ResultActivity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                //}
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.option, menu);
        return true;
    }
    private void setQuestionView()
    {
        textView.setText(currentQ.getQuestion1());
        textView2.setText(currentQ.getQuestion2());
        textView3.setText(currentQ.getQuestion3());
        textView4.setText(currentQ.getQuestion4());
        qid++;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View layoutview, DragEvent dragevent) {


        int action = dragevent.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:

                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

                View view = (View) dragevent.getLocalState();

                TextView droptarget = (TextView) layoutview;
                TextView dropped = (TextView) view;

                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (droptarget.getText().toString() != dropped.getText().toString()) {
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    droptarget.setText(dropped.getText().toString());


                    //update the text in the target view to reflect the data being dropped
                    //make it bold to highlight the fact that an item has been dropped
                    //if an item has already been dropped here, there will be a tag
                    Object tag = droptarget.getTag();
                    //if there is already an item here, set it back visible in its original place
                    if (tag != null) {
                        //the tag is the view id already dropped here
                        int existingID = (Integer) tag;
                        //set the original view visible again
                        findViewById(existingID).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    //set the tag in the target view being dropped on - to the ID of the view being dropped
                    droptarget.setTag(dropped.getId());


                        butNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 //remove setOnDragListener by setting OnDragListener to null, so that no further drag & dropping on this TextView can be done
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "false", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;

        } else {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;

        }`enter code here`
    }
}`
```

Comment: Do you want the user to drag the correct textbox into another one?

Comment: Please add the code. It will help clarify what problem you are facing.

Comment: please help me guys i have added my codes with it..